# ZF2 - Trying to create a route like ZF1

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-framework-routing

I actually have 2 modules (Application and Admin) in my ZF2 application and I want a url routing like in ZF1. I currently have the following route:

```js
'router' => array
(

    'routes' => array
    (

        'admin' => array
        (

            'type' => 'Segment',
            'options' => array
            (

                'route' => 'admin/[:controller[/:action]]',

                'constraints' => array
                (
                    'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                ),

                'defaults' => array
                (
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Admin\Controller',
                    'controller' => 'Index',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),

            ),

            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array
            (

                'wildcard' => array
                (

                    'type' => 'Wildcard'

                )

            )

        ),

    ),

),
```

So it will match "/admin", "/admin/controller", "/admin/controller/action" but not "/controller/action".

Now I need a route to the Application module. The problem is that if I simply use a route like that for the module Application, this new route would match "/admin/controller" as controller = "admin" and action = "controller".

I also tried the following regex route in the application:

```js
'application' => array
        (

            'type' => 'Regex',
            'options' => array
            (

                'regex' => '/(?<controller>^(?!(admin)$)[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)?' . 
                            '(/[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)?',
                'spec' => '/%controller%/%action%',

                /*'constraints' => array
                (
                    //The controller cannot be "admin"
                    'controller' => '^(?!(admin)$)[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                ),*/

                'defaults' => array
                (
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                    'controller' => 'Index',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),

            ),

            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array
            (

                'wildcard' => array
                (

                    'type' => 'Wildcard'

                )

            )

        ),
```

But it's not getting the variables "controller" and "action".

Does anyone have a suggestion of how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

mind the route order: routes are handled using a LIFO stack, so what comes last in the array comes first when matching request urls.

this means that you always have to define the most generic routes first to prevent them from matching similar but more specific ones.

using the following order shouldn't need any constraint on the `controller` parameter, because anything starting with `/admin` will be matched first

```
'route1' => array(
    'type' => 'Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
        'defaults' => array (
            'controller' => 'controller',
            'action' => 'index',
        ),
    ),
),
'route2' => array(
    'type' => 'Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/admin[/:controller[/:action]]',
        'defaults' => array (
            'controller' => 'admin-controller',
            'action' => 'index',
        ),
    ),
),
```

furthermore, you can always specify excplicitly routes priority using the `priority` property (which should not be defined under the `options` array, but in the topmost array of the route), so the following code is equivalent to the previous example:

```
'route2' => array(
    'type' => 'Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/admin[/:controller[/:action]]',
        'defaults' => array (
            'controller' => 'admin-controller',
            'action' => 'index',
        ),
    ),
),
'route1' => array(
    'type' => 'Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
        'defaults' => array (
            'controller' => 'controller',
            'action' => 'index',
        ),
    ),
    'priority' => -1,
),
```